# How can I automatically log use of any @Deprecated annoted method in Java?

Tags: java, logging, annotations

I'm currently using slf4j on top of log4j for logging. I would like to automagically log any use of a deprecated method (annotated with the standard @Deprecated annotation) in my code.

Is there any easy way to do this ?

Comment: Is there any reason this can't be done at compile time? Ok, you might find instances where something is referenced but never actually used but you should get a clear overview of what deprecated methods are (possibly) being invoked.

Comment: This can be done at compile time, but the solution has to be pretty easy to do, as it may not be me that will do that job :)

We're using Maven2, I think we can use APT to do this, I don't know how to use APT with Maven yet. I've read APT is inside Javac using JDK6, but most developers ares using JDK5 right now in my company to build their programs, so it may not be the easiest solution.

Comment: I can think of one situation where this could be useful, which is calls to deprecated routes in a `@RestController`. But I suppose it's easier to just manually add a `WARN` level log event at the same time as deprecating the method.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to log every use you will probably have to use [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). It depends on what Frameworks you are using if there is an easy way to do this. This is how it might look like in [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html):

```
public class DeprecatedLoggerAdvice implements MethodInterceptor
{
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable
    {
        Methode method = invocation.getMethod();
        Annotation[] annotations = method.getAnnotations();
        boolean isDeprecated = // Check it annotations has the deprecated one in here
        if(isDeprecated)
        {
            log.warn("Called deprecated method {}", method.getName());
        }
        invocation.proceed();
    }
}
```

Though as already mentioned this is not good on performance. If you are using it in your application you should use that approach in combination with unit tests that cover most of your code. Then you can log and remove the use of deprecated methods and then disable AOP in production mode.

Comment: Can this apply to non Spring beans ? We're using Spring, however I would like to deprecate some getters & setters in my entities, so they aren't beans themselves.

I believe we can make a Maven profile or a value in a property in order to remove this in production mode

Comment: That will only be possible with compile time weaving (cglib), meaning that you will have to enable AspectJ support. I found that always to be quite a hassle but check out the documentation http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html on how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of an **easy** way to do it, but you could use the [annotation processing tool](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/index.html) to generate code that logs the use of each deprecated method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be sorry if you did this at runtime. Sure you could use Aspect4J to put an AOP pointcut on every method that looks for annotations; but the performance cost would be high.

Comment: Don't know about aspect4j but with AspectJ you can just define a pointcut based on @Deprected annotation so only those methods get the advice applied, anything else is unaffected

Answer (score 0):

You can but it is going to be tough. The only solution AFAIK to "detect" method calls is by using AOP. In your case, you can write an aspect which inspects every single method call and checks if it is deprecated and logs them.

If you use spring you can start http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html

Please be advised that AOP has performance implications and should be used only after giving careful consideration. Perhaps you can have a flag that enables this feature in a dev/qa environment and disables them in PROD